# AWS Athens regexp_extract

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I am trying to extract a part of the string 'c://abcd /abcdef/0012wetr_1234567890.csv' between the last '/' and '_' characters.

> 0012wetr

I am able to extract everything after the last '/' character

`select regexp_extract('c://abcd /abcdef/0012wetr_1234567890.csv', '([^/]*)$');`

> 0012wetr_1234567890.csv

Unfortunately I am stuck and don't know how to split it further.

Your help would be appreciated. Cheers, A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `REGEXP_REPLACE` approach:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE('c://abcd /abcdef/0012wetr_1234567890.csv', '.*/([^_]+).*', '$1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iRZM3m/2).

If you need to keep the result blank if there is no match, add `|.+` at the end of the pattern:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE('c://abcd /abcdef/0012wetr_1234567890.csv', '.*/([^_]+).*|.+', '$1')
```

*Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `/` - a `/` char
- `([^_]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than `_`
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `|` - or
- `.+` - any one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is overkill but I managed to get required result using next combination of lookaheads - `(?!\/)[^\/]+(?=_)`:

```sql
select regexp_extract('c://abcd /abcdef/0012wetr_1234567890.csv', '(?!\/)[^\/]+(?=_)');
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 0012wetr |

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bDLJC0/1)